# Decrypting RSA encrypted data from C# in Java. Format of encrypted data?

Tags: java, c#, rsa

I am using RSA encryption to encrypt some data in C#. Now I want to decrypt the encrypted data in Java.
But I've encountered some problems.

The main problem probably is to get the encrypted message from c# to java.
In c# we have unsigned bytes and the endian is different

So, for testing I am converting the `byte` array of the encrypted data in c# to a `sbyte` array and get a string representation of it.
Then I copy the string representation of the byte array into my java code and convert it back to an 'byte' array. After that, I reverse the array to match the endianess of java.

But if I try to decode the data that was like above transferred, I get following exception:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Message is larger than modulus

Encrypting and decrypting from C# to C# works as well as from java to java. only C# to java won't work. (the string to encrypt has a length of 7 characters, so it is not really to long)

I am converting the public key in c# to a `BigInteger`. The public key is delivered from the `RSAParameters`:

```
 public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] data, RSAParameters param, bool padding) {
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024)) {
            rsaProvider.ImportParameters(param);

            byte[] modulusArray = param.Modulus;
            byte[] exponentArray = param.Exponent;

            BigInteger modulusBigInt = new BigInteger(modulusArray);

            BigInteger exponentBigInt = new BigInteger(exponentArray);

            encryptedData = rsaProvider.Encrypt(data, false);

            return encryptedData;
        }
    }
```

After that I copy the string representations of the modulus and exponent into my java code and create new `BigInteger` from them and create the public key:

```
    BigInteger modulusBigInt = new BigInteger(modulusBytesStr);
    BigInteger exponentBigInt = getBigIntFromByteString(exponentBytesStr);

    Key pK = getPublicKey(modulusBigInt, exponentBigInt);
```

Then I try to decrypt the data (where data is the byte array that I transferred from c# to java like described above):

```
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pK);

        decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

But if i try so, I am getting the exception mentioned above. The public key should be right, I think. At least I have the same `BigInteger` values of the modulus and the exponent in c# and in java. The padding is equal, too.
 So I am assuming that there is something wrong with the format of my encrypted data. Which fromat should it have?

I have also read this question: [RSA .NET encryption Java decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572897/rsa-net-encryption-java-decryption)
But even after that I am not sure what format my data to encryspt/decrypt should have

EDIT: tried to convert the encrypted bytes in c# to a `Base64 String` and in java converting it back to bytes. Also not working

EDIT2: If I am using `var key = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(true);` to get the xml represantation of the public key and putting the xml strings of the modulus and exponents in my java code, converting them from Base64 string to byte array and from byte array to BigInteger, then I am getting another value of the BigInteger of the modulus as the BigInteger had in c#, but I get follwing exception with this values: `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error`

EDIT3: Found my error: For simple testing I just used the private key that I generated in my C# code to decrypt in java. But in my java code I tried to generate a public key from the private key.

```
     RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pK = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

Thats clearly wrong. So I changed this to:

```
 RSAPrivateKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulusBigInt, exponentBigInt);

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        Key key = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
```

And it worked. Thats also why the method of GregS worked (there was no 'PublicKey'/'PrivateKey' generated and for the decryption was not the java build in method used)

Comment: Suggestion: don't try to encrypt and decrypt to begin with.  Figure out a way of transferring binary data from C# to Java, and then once that piece works, tack the encryption on it.

Comment: Figured out a way: Using base64 strings (as in my very first try, before I tried to transfer bytes directly, because nothing worked). So, as you can see in my EDIT2, base64 strings doesn't work either. And based on base64 strings the BigInteger-values of the modulus are different in c# and java .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unclear as to exactly where you are going wrong. Here is an example that works for me that I based off of your code. I don't have a windows machine so I tested this in Mono.

C#:

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace RsaDotNetToJava
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] data, RSAParameters param, bool padding) {
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024)) {
                rsaProvider.ImportParameters(param);

                var encryptedData = rsaProvider.Encrypt(data, false);

                return encryptedData;
            }
        }

        public static void W(string label, byte [] x) {
            var b64 = Convert.ToBase64String (x);
            Console.WriteLine ("{0} = {1}", label, b64);
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var x = new MainClass ();
            var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider (1024);
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world");
            var parms = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
            W ("Modulus", parms.Modulus);
            W ("P", parms.P);
            W ("DecryptExponent", parms.D);
            W ("EncryptExponent", parms.Exponent);
            var cipher = x.RSAEncrypt(data, parms, false);
            W ("Cipher", cipher);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, some Java that reads in the base64 strings with ("label = " stripped off) from the command line and does some manipulations. This uses the java 7 class `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` for its base64 parser.

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class RsaJavaToDotNet {


    private static BigInteger b64ToBigInteger(String b64) {
        byte [] bigEndianBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(b64);
        return new BigInteger(1, bigEndianBytes); 
    }

    /**
     * @param args base64 encoded .NET big-endian integer arrays
     *    args[0] = modulus
     *    args[1] = prime
     *    args[2] = decrypt exponent
     *    args[3] = encrypt exponent
     *    args[4] = cipher
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BigInteger modulus = b64ToBigInteger(args[0]);
        final int modulusByteLength = (modulus.bitLength() + 7) / 8;
        BigInteger prime = b64ToBigInteger(args[1]);
        BigInteger d = b64ToBigInteger(args[2]);
        BigInteger e = b64ToBigInteger(args[3]);
        BigInteger cipherInt = b64ToBigInteger(args[4]);

        // Decrypt the cipher

        BigInteger plainInt = cipherInt.modPow(d, modulus);
        byte [] plain = plainInt.toByteArray();

        // Verify the format and extract the message.

        if (plain.length != (modulusByteLength - 1) || plain[0] != 2) {
            throw new Exception("Something is wrong");
        }

        // Find the zero byte delimited the payload from the padding

        int zeroPos = 1;
        while (zeroPos < plain.length && plain[zeroPos] != 0) {
            ++zeroPos;
        }

        String plainStr = new String(plain, zeroPos + 1, plain.length - zeroPos - 1, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(plainStr);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is working. After I tried to adapt it to my code and failed, I just copied it for testing and it worked. So, now I try to figure out where the errors in my code are.

Answer (score -1):

> So, for testing I am converting the byte array of the encrypted data in c# to a sbyte array and get a string representation of it. Then I copy the string representation of the byte array into my java code and convert it back to an 'byte' array. After that, I reverse the array to match the endianess of java.

I don't quite get why "endianness" is an issue here. Endianism is a function of the CPU you're running on, not the programming language.

Comment: If I have follwing byte array; `byte[] b = new byte[]{120,110,100}` and want to convert it into a BigInteger in java and c# than I have in c# a value of 6581880 and in java a value of 7892580. Only reversing the array in java (or in c#) will get the same result. 

My question now would be: Is it necessary to have the same values of the BigIntegers for the public key in java and c# or could I ignore the order of the byte-arrays?

Comment: But it doesn't matter anymore, because even if I use base64 strings to get the public key (modulus, exponent) and the encrypted message to java (and converting the modulus and exponent strings to BigIntegers), I get an exception.

Comment: Endianness is not just a CPU feature.  Endianness matters any time there is a mapping between a sequence of binary integers of one size, and some longer sequence of smaller binary integers.  Such mapping can occur when a CPU accesses memory in different size chunks.  It also can be a concern in network protocols and in file formats.  It's a concern in programming languages that have "union" data types (e.g., C/C++), and it's a concern in libraries that "serialize" objects.  Protocols/languages/libraries may specify an endianness, or they may allow it to depend on the underlying hardware.